# LogStash - Local DNS lookup

Tags: dns, logstash

Im new with LogStash and I cant figure out some simple questions.

I need to add a DNS info taken from a local DNS server to manage lockup for internal IP.

My local DNS server has an IP, for example 10.1.0.20

I need to read the source.ip and destination.ip and add new information with DNS data.

The official DOC says:

```
filter {
      dns {
        reverse => [ "source_host", "field_with_address" ]
        resolve => [ "field_with_fqdn" ]
        action => "replace"
      }
    }
```

But Its not clear where I have to put my data.

I want an output like:

```
"source" => 
{ 
  ...
  "address" : "192.168.1.29",
  "dns_info" : "Desktop123"
  ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the DNS filter tries to resolve the address or name *in place* instead of adding a field... so you need to jump through hoops. Assuming you have a doc with an `source.ip` field...

```rb
filter {

  mutate {
    copy => { "[source][ip]" => "[source][fqdn]" }
  }

  dns {
    reverse => "[source][fqdn]"
    action => "replace"
    add_field => { "[@metadata][dns_source]" => "success" }
  }

  if ![@metadata][dns_source] {
    mutate { remove_field => "[source][fqdn]" }
  }

}
```

It's ugly, but I don't know of a better way to do this given there is no `target` setting for the DNS filter plugin.

I think this answers the crux of your question; other things, like specifying a nameserver or setting cache times, are well covered in the official docs.